# calling a webservice from scheduled task agent class in windows phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Can we call a webservice from the scheduled periodic task class firstly, if yes,
Am trying to call a webservice method with parameters in scheduled periodic task agent class in windows phone 7.1. am getting a null reference exception while calling the method though am passing the expected values to the parameters for the webmethod.
am retrieving the id from the isolated storage.

the following is my code.

```
 protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        if (task is PeriodicTask)
        {
            string Name = IName;
            string Desc = IDesc;
            updateinfo(Name, Desc);
        }
    }



public void updateinfo(string name, string desc)
    {
        AppSettings tmpSettings = Tr.AppSettings.Load();
        id = tmpSettings.myString;
        if (name == "" && desc == "")
        {
            name = "No Data";
            desc = "No Data";
        }
        tservice.UpdateLogAsync(id, name,desc);
        tservice.UpdateLogCompleted += new EventHandler<STservice.UpdateLogCompletedEventArgs>(t_UpdateLogCompleted);
    }
```

Someone please help me resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this before without a problem.  The one thing you need to make sure of is that you wait until your async read processes have completed before you call `NotifyComplete();`.

Here's an example from one of my apps.  I had to remove much of the logic, but it should show you how the flow goes.  This uses a slightly modified version of WebClient where I added a Timeout, but the principles are the same with the service that you're calling... Don't call `NotifyComplete()` until the end of `t_UpdateLogCompleted`

Here's the example code:

```cs
    private void UpdateTiles(ShellTile appTile)
    {
        try
        {
            var wc = new WebClientWithTimeout(new Uri("URI Removed")) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) };
            wc.DownloadAsyncCompleted += (src, e) =>
            {

                try
                {
                     //process response 
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Handle exception
                }
                finally
                {
                    FinishUp();
                }
            };


            wc.StartReadRequestAsync();
   }



    private void FinishUp()
    {
#if DEBUG
        try
        {
            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(_taskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("relaunching in 30 seconds");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
#endif
        NotifyComplete();

    }
```

Comment: Resolved: Actually I have forgot to initialize my webservice to new instance in the constructor. Now, its working fine. Thanks for your help.